# issues with trend line generation

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

So I have this issue with my trend line graphs where when I have them on there own file it works, but when I put them into my project is puts this weird text at the bottom, any help is appreciated,

Code is for the working trendline:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        ,width=7cm
        ,xlabel=Test
        ,ylabel=Mean
        ,xtick=data,
       %,xtick={0,1,...,3}
        ,xticklabels={Test A,Test B,Test C,Test D}
        ]
        \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
        {(0,18.26) (1,21.47) (2,24.58) (3,24.95)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what it outputs when I put it into my main file and I can't find a reason why it does this. https://ibb.co/xJxVWG6

I'm using headboxes to house them and and on the main page I declare like:

```
%PAGE TYPE DECLARING
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{baposter}
%Colour mode style
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
```

Comment: Fixed it!
So it turns out it was being buggy cause I had 
```\DTLassignfirstmatch{attacks}{count}{1}{\count=count,\onepoints=points,\onename=name}```

and the \count must be used in the package so had to change it to 
```\DTLassignfirstmatch{attacks}{count}{1}{\counted=count,\onepoints=points,\onename=name}```
And now it works!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you want to make your question more useful for future visitors it would be good to add a small document to the question that shows the issue (i.e., including the datatool commands with `\count`) and then add a self-answer to the question where you fix the problem. Alternatively we can also close the question as "needs more detail" (the example described above would be the "more detail") or as "cannot be reproduced/typo".